# error: attribute dotsSpacing not found Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-cardview, android-viewpager2

"I have this activity_guide.xml layout file. Although dotSpacing is present it shows error that

ERROR:C:\Users\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_guide.xml:41: AAPT: error: attribute dotsSpacing (aka com.MyApp.Video:dotsSpacing) not found.

How to fix this error?"

```
android:background="#424242"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/guide_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:tint="@android:color/white" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/controller"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:dotsColor="@android:color/white"
    app:dotsCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:dotsSize="8dp"
    app:dotsWidthFactor="2.5"
    app:progressMode="true"
    app:selectedDotColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:dotsSpacing= "4dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/controller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/info_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:shadow_Outer_Area="0dp"
        app:corner_Type="circular"
        app:background_Color="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_new_24"
            android:background="#AE818181"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/guide_bg"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

"This error started after upgrading to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2"

Comment: It is related `app:dotsSpacing= "4dp"` in your `ViewPager`. Remove that attribute if you don't want it

Comment: It gave another error on removing: "ERROR:C:\Users\MyApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_guide.xml:41: AAPT: error: attribute dotsCornerRadius (aka com.MyApp.Video:dotsCornerRadius) not found.
"

Comment: I suddenly started getting this issue. I wasn't getting this until yesterday.